# Image Matching using NCC (normalized cross-correlation)

Tags: python, opencv, cross-correlation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQpKG.png)
I have tried to implement NCC on two images but my code works only on small images when I try to input big images it's saying doing processing(Matching) without any output.
can anyone tell me where is the problem please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou8Ta.png)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Normalized Cross Correlation
def ncc(roi, template):
    mean_roi = np.mean(roi)
    mean_template = np.mean(template)
    numerator = np.sum((roi - mean_roi) * (template - mean_template))
    denominator = np.sqrt(np.sum((roi - mean_roi) ** 2)) * np.sqrt(np.sum((template - mean_template) ** 2))
    return numerator / denominator

# Template Matching using NCC
def template_matching_ncc(image, template):   
    h, w = template.shape
    H, W = image.shape
    print("Template Matching using NCC")

    max_ncc = -1
    max_position = (0, 0)


    for y in range(H - h):
        for x in range(W - w):
            roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            current_ncc = ncc(roi, template)
            print("Matching")
            if current_ncc > max_ncc:
                max_ncc = current_ncc
                max_position = (x, y)
                print("max_position Matching")

    return max_position

# Read the images
print("Loading first image")
image = cv2.imread('./0711_study_area1.jpg', 0)  # Replace with your image path
print("Loading Second image")
template = cv2.imread('./0711_study_areaa.jpg', 0)  # Replace with your template path

print("Apply template matching")
# Apply template matching
top_left = template_matching_ncc(image, template)
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + template.shape[1], top_left[1] + template.shape[0])

# Draw a rectangle on the matched region
print("Draw a rectangle on the matched region")
cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

# Show the result
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.title("Template Matching using NCC")
plt.show()
```

Comment: please upload the images

Comment: thanks for your replay, it's just print for me Matchinag which means still working inside the loop and doesn't stop.

Comment: I mean the images that you are reading with `cv2.imread`

Comment: Why don't you just use cv2.matchTemplate().  I believe that NCC is just TM_COEFF_NORMED. What you are doing is going to be extremely slow!

Comment: yes, thank you so much it's working with cv2.matchTemplate() very well.